# get text from active word document

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to get text from active winword window on top of that I want to get .doc file path from where the active window as opened.

How can I do this with C#?

I am doing window base application using C#.net.

Answer (score 2):

first of all, I think you should using FindWindow.

Then you can get file name which is opened.

Comment: I can find winword.exe. but I can not find the document file that was opened by winword.exe , right?